# Amazon S3 Put Object 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: amazon-s3

I have tried to upload directly to Amazon S3 bucket using client side SDK. My code is based on this post : http://www.cheynewallace.com/uploading-to-s3-with-angularjs/. I can do the upload and view the files using S3 console.However when I try to execute putObject from Client  side I am getting 403 error. Pls help me figure out where am I going wrong.

CORS settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>x-amz-acl</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

2. Bucket Policy 


    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Id": "Policy1460109621028",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "Stmt1460109523730",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                    "s3:PutObject"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::zxcvbucketdemo123/*",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::zxcvbucketdemo123"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

3. IAM policy



 {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "s3:*",
          "Resource": "*"
        }
      ]
    }



4. Controller.js

app.controller('DemoCtrl123', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.sizeLimit      = 10585760; // 10MB in Bytes
  $scope.uploadProgress = 0;
  $scope.creds={} ;

$scope.creds.bucket='zxcvbucketdemo123';
$scope.creds.access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$scope.creds.secret_key='yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

  $scope.upload = function() {
       console.log("inside amazon s3 controller upload function....");
    AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: $scope.creds.access_key, secretAccessKey: $scope.creds.secret_key });
    AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket } });
    console.log($scope.creds.bucket);
    console.log(bucket);
    if($scope.file) {
        // Perform File Size Check First
        /*var fileSize = Math.round(parseInt($scope.file.size));
        console.log(filesize);
        if (fileSize > $scope.sizeLimit) {
          toastr.error('Sorry, your attachment is too big. <br/> Maximum '  + $scope.fileSizeLabel() + ' file attachment allowed','File Too Large');
          return false;
        }*/

        // Prepend Unique String To Prevent Overwrites
        var uniqueFileName = $scope.uniqueString() + '-' + $scope.file.name;

        // var params = { Key: uniqueFileName, ContentType: $scope.file.type, Body: $scope.file, ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256' };
         var params = { Key: uniqueFileName, ContentType: $scope.file.type, Body: $scope.file};
        console.log(params);
        console.log(uniqueFileName);
        console.log($scope.file.type);
        console.log($scope.file);

        bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
          if(err) {
            console.log("inside amazon s3 controller putobject error....");
            toastr.error(err.message,err.code);
            return false;
          }
          else {
            // Upload Successfully Finished
            console.log("inside amazon s3 controller upload succesful....");
            toastr.success('File Uploaded Successfully', 'Done');

            // Reset The Progress Bar
            setTimeout(function() {
              $scope.uploadProgress = 0;
              $scope.$digest();
            }, 4000);
          }
        })
        .on('httpUploadProgress',function(progress) {
          $scope.uploadProgress = Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100);
          $scope.$digest();
        });
      }
      else {
        // No File Selected
        toastr.error('Please select a file to upload');
      }
    }

    $scope.fileSizeLabel = function() {
    // Convert Bytes To MB
    return Math.round($scope.sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) + 'MB';
  };

  $scope.uniqueString = function() {
    var text     = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 8; i++ ) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
  }

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me adding:

```
<ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
```

inside the `<CORSRule>` solved this exact problem.

Comment: @Abhi.Rathore did it help?

Comment: Yes it did.Though eventually I resorted to uploading file in S3 via Django back end instead of Angular.